# Simple standard command line test to verify Python module is successfully installed

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a simple test from the command line (zsh Catalina / bash Ubuntu) that verify installation of a python module?

For example: if `pip3 install reportlab` is executed, does execution of from the python prompt:

'>>> import reportlab

positively confirm that module is successfully installed?  What are the limits (false positives) of this test?

Answer (score 1):

`pip show` followed by the name of the package.

For example:

```
pip show pyyaml
```

Will output something like this:

```
Name: PyYAML
Version: 5.3.1
Summary: YAML parser and emitter for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml
Author: Kirill Simonov
Author-email: xi@resolvent.net
License: MIT
Location: d:\_venvs\python36\test-geo\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: yamllint
```

You can also use `pip list` and `pip freeze` to display a list of installed packages.